# Redirect from localhost to external url

Tags: http, redirect, networking, https, localhost

I want to redirect a local port door to a website. So that when I access `https://localhost:8080` it actually loads (or redirects) `https://www.facebook.com`, or something like that.

I'm on a windows machine. I already tried changing the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` but it did not work.

I only found solutions of the other way around. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a reverse proxy to implement this feature. The data flow would look like:

Browser -> `localhost:8080` -> proxy server that listen port 8080 on localhost -> proxy server sends request to `example.com` -> proxy server receives response from `example.com` and return to browser -> Browser

This reverse proxy can be programmed manually, or by using HTTP proxy software, such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/):

[image]

Comment: I see. I didn't know "Reverse Proxy" was the name for what I wanted to do. Thank you a lot!